# AVD Pixel_XL_API_30, emulator process gets killed every time in Android

Tags: android-emulator, crashes

I just downloaded Android Studio's latest version being: 4.1.3 (18 March 2021) with the repository being: android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea. The problem is that my AVD Manager is unable to load any of the Virtual Devices, however, light it might be. Currently, I am using Pixel_XL_API_30.

[image: My AVD Manager]

It shows "The emulator process for AVD Pixel_XL_API_30 was killed."

[image: Crashes Everytime]

Can anyone tell me if this new version problem or is a bug?

Comment: Make sure that your CPU supports virtualization technology and it is enabled in BIOS. Install also the appropriate support package for Intel CPU (HAXM) respectively the other package for AMD CPUs. Make sure your computer has enough RAM - min 8GB.

Answer (score 2):

The most frequent reasons for this is

1. Windows: Not enough disk-space on drive C: (where Android stores its emulators)
2. Enabled Windows hypervisor!

   - Hit Windows-Key and enter 'features', select 'enable/disable Windows Features'
   - Disable 'Windows Hypervisor Platform' (this disables Windows Subsystem for Linux as well)

This worked for me, you currently can't have both unfortunately even in Windows Pro.

*Edit:* There seems to be a [solution with Hyper-V](https://techgenix.com/running-an-android-emulator-on-hyper-v/)

Comment: Yup, for me, it was not enough disk space. Thank you

Comment: Please mark as the accepted answer, thanks.